# Shared user accounts between two asp.net applications on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am relativly new to asp.net.

So, I have two independent asp.net projects. Both have their own Login. Both are running on localhost. Both have their own DB.

Now, if I start one of them, log in and then start the other project, I am being logged in with the user of the first project, even though, that user does not exist in this one.

For uservalidation I am using `Microsoft.Identity`.

Since, its local, it does not matter much, however, I have no idea why this happens. My guess is, that it happens because both run on the same server (IIS), but its only a guess.

So, why am I being logged in even though the account doesn't exist in one of the projects and can anything happen, when both are deployed like that?